# MonthName always returns December

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a dropdown box in Excel 2010 to select a month (January, February, March...December).  My macro used to work in Excel 2007 to populate an email's subjectline with the selected month from the dropdown.  Since upgrading to Excel 2010 this code now puts "December" as the month no matter what month is selected.

```
Dim Person0 As String
Dim Person1 As String
Dim SubjectOfEmail As String
Dim MonthNum As Integer
Dim ThisMonth As String
Dim ThisYear As String
Dim ThisYear2 As String

MonthNum = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
ThisMonth = MonthName(MonthNum)
ThisYear = ActiveSheet.Name

Person0 = "myemail@gmail.com"
Person1 = "DistributionList"

SubjectOfEmail = ThisMonth & " " & ThisYear & " Desk Schedule"
```

Comment: debug it and look at what `MonthNum` value is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several pages (2012, 2013, 2014, 2015); there was also a macro for each page.  When the macros were placed in alpabetical order the one that ran was pointing at 2014's page instead of 2015.  That page was set on December still.  So long story short- check where your macros are running.